# unknown characters in password field entered by iOS user

Tags: php, ios, unicode

I was wondering what's these characters?

`'password' => '\\376kq4v\\005\\213\\363\\257\\021\\347\\137\\251\\262\\023\\133\\125\\157\\010\\122\\374'`

It's PHP's `var_export()` output of user posted data for a **password** field in form. Actual value was 'kq4v'.

How to handle these special characters? Does `trim()` help? As it is password field, I think trimming input will cause bad side-effects.. (what if user password starts with spaces?)

**Note:** User set device language to a middle-eastern language. (Arabic I think)

Comment: Why do you need to handle it? If the hashes match, you can validate the password.

Comment: @jeroen: it was hashed without these characters.. and user reported a this as a problem..